# How to keep one level of object and extract one of its sub-key only?

Tags: json, nested, jq

I'm playing a bit with terraform state json output and want to transform it a bit.

Given that input issued from terraform:

```
{
  "cost": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "value": "123"
  },
  "test_id": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "value": "6610758455459338306"
  }
}
```

How do i convert it to something usefull for my application like bellow:

```
{
  "cost": "123",
  "test_id": "6610758455459338306"
}
```

I tried to play with `from_entries`, `with_entries` but i'm a complete noob at it

Comment: Precision: using `jq` 1.6 (on MacOs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`map_values`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)). It works just like `map`, but doesn't convert an object input to an array.

```
map_values(.value)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/oE-Gw5OxxD)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

[oguz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65883403/5291015) is crisp and to the point, but if you want to do with `*_entries` functions, you could getaway with

```
with_entries(.value = .value.value)
```

<sup>[jqplay - snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/WL9PW5SGtB)</sup>